# Is it correct to say that in a String variable all ASCII symbols can be stored?

Tags: java, html, string, ascii

I want to know whether by definition it would be correct to say "A string variable can contain every ASCII symbol" without relating to length limitations. Or is a String Variable unable to store some Symbols? And if so is there a difference in said limitation between an HTML input field and a i.e. Java String Variable?

Comment: For Java, I would say that is correct, but incomplete.  See the java String definition (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), in which it states that 'A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format'.  UTF-16 can represent more than just ASCII.  But, it does include all the ASCII symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be equally odd to describe text in HTML as ASCII as it would be in Java. Text in HTML is from the Unicode character set. Text data types in Java use the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set.

The designers of [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) include characters from almost all other computerized character sets. You are probably familiar with many . (The characters from the ISO 8859-1 character set are incorporated into Unicode with identical numbers as the first 256 codepoints. (The characters from the ASCII character set are incorporated into the ISO 8859-1 character set with identical numbers as the first 128 codepoints.))

Although Unicode is huge (the codepoint space is 21 bits, but only 0 to 1114111), the practical limits on the length of text in Java implementations and HTML processors should far exceed that. Also, HTML inputs are typically posted back to a web server using HTTP. There shouldn't generally be a problem with that except on web servers running on tiny devices.

Answer (score 2):

String Variable allows you to store any ASCII characters.

```
String allSymbolsASCII = IntStream.range(0, 128)
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i).map(c -> c.toString())
    .collect(Collectors.joining());
IntStream.range(0, allSymbolsASCII.length())
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println("" + i + " = " + allSymbolsASCII.charAt(i)));
```

Comment: Nice explanation by code but it needs a big comment to explain the relationship between UTF-16 code unit (`char`) values and ASCII.